# I can't connect to my MySQL/MariaDB database using a JDBC driver (android studio)

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I had trouble getting jdbc driver for my android project...
I tried to check the runtime logs to check for errors and I narrow it down to *conn* variable is not setting with the the values I provided. My parsed variables like the names, gender, and birthdate (arranged in yyyy-mm-dd) are set with my desired variables.
I tried two different drivers (mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar [provided by a tutorial I just followed] and mariadb-java-client-2.7.4.jar [latest jdbc driver since I'm using MariaDB on my database server]) in my app/libs folder in my project and yielded the same result (conn is still null).

connBridgeUserDataSQL.java

```
package test.application;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class connBridgeUserDataSQL {
    String SQLDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; //use the MySQL driver as a java class
    //MySQL credentials
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://(insert ip address here)/(insert SQL database here)"; //MySQL server host
    String un = "demo_username"; //MySQL username
    String password = "demo_pasword"; //MySQL password

    //creates connection to MySQL
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = url;
        //output to log (for debugging only)
        Log.d("SQL url: ", url);
        Log.d("SQL username: ", un);
        Log.d("SQL password: ", password);
        try {

            Class.forName(SQLDriver);

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, un, password);

            //conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        }
        catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Snippet of code from EditPersonalInfo.java

```
//typically included as a global variable
connBridgeUserDataSQL connBridgeUserDataSQL; 
 //Java class for updating personal info
    public class AsyncUpdatePersonalInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        //convert to string (personal info)
        String NewFirstName = EditFirstName.getText().toString(); //first name
        String NewMiddleName = EditMiddleName.getText().toString(); //middle name
        String NewLastname = EditLastName.getText().toString(); //last name
        String NewSex = ((RadioButton) findViewById(RadioGroupUpdateSex.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString(); //sex
        String NewBirthDate = TempUpdateBDate; //birthday
        String userIDGlobal;
        String toastNotify = "Hello"; //temporary variable for toast
        boolean isSuccess = false; //if update info is successful
        boolean verifyChecks = true; //verification checks

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            /*progressDialog.setMessage("Updating personal info");
            progressDialog.show();*/
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Updating user data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //debug checks just to make sure the values aren't null
            Log.d("Firstname", NewFirstName);
            Log.d("Middlename", NewMiddleName);
            Log.d("Lastname", NewLastname);
            Log.d("Gender", NewGender);
            Log.d("Birthdate", NewBirthDate);
            //getting the current user sharedPreferences (to be used in userID)
            User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(EditPersonalInfo.this).getUser();
            String userID = user.getuserID();
            userIDGlobal = userID;
            Log.d("userID", userIDGlobal);
        }

        //background task to communicate into database
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            //if name fields are empty, return failed on verifyChecks
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(NewFirstName)) {
                verifyChecks = false;
                EditFirstName.setError("Enter first name");
                EditFirstName.requestFocus();
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(NewMiddleName)) {
                verifyChecks = false;
                EditMiddleName.setError("Enter middle name");
                EditMiddleName.requestFocus();
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(NewLastname)) {
                verifyChecks = false;
                EditLastName.setError("Enter middle name");
                EditLastName.requestFocus();
            }
            //invalid age
            if (validAge = false){
                verifyChecks = false;
                buttonUpdateSetBirthDate.setError("Enter valid age");
                buttonUpdateSetBirthDate.requestFocus();
            }
            //if verification checks failed
            if (verifyChecks = false) {
                toastNotify = "Please check for empty fields";
            } else {
                try {
                    Connection con = connBridgeUserDataSQL.CONN(); //connect to MySQL
                    //if no network connection, notify user to check their network connection
                    if (con == null) {
                        toastNotify = "Updating personal info requires an internet connection. Please try again";
                        //a response to the debug log that the SQL connection is null
                        Log.e("SQL Connector", "Currently set to NULL");
                    } 
                    else {
                        //Copy userID for the password to be updated
                        String userID = userIDGlobal;
                        //update password to database
                        String query = "UPDATE `users` SET `firstname` = '" + NewFirstName + "' , `middlename` = '" + NewMiddleName + "' , `lastname` = '" + NewLastname + "', `birthdate` = '" + NewBirthDate + "', `gender` = '" + NewGender + "' WHERE `userID` = '" + userIDGlobal + "';";
                        //show query to log
                       Log.d("SQL QUERY: ", query);
                        //Update SQL
                        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
                        //Say update successful afterwards (if conditions are met)
                        toastNotify = "Personal info updated!";
                        isSuccess = true;
                    }
                }
                //if failed, create a toast saying update failed or something
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    isSuccess = false;
                    toastNotify = "SQL Exception: " + ex;
                }
            }
            return toastNotify;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            //show the appropriate toast message
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + toastNotify, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //progressDialog.hide();
            //finish();
        }
    }
```

P.S.: Any optional optimizations are welcome.

Comment: You should not use JDBC drivers from Android, but instead use a REST API to mediate between your application and your database. Also, recent versions of MySQL Connector/J will not even work on Android because it uses features not available on Android.

Comment: And if you get a `null` connection, then check your logs: you catch exception and continue on as if nothing happened.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I slightly modify the error output yesturday and it returns a "Class not found exception".  A REST api might be a better solution overall than this one but I'm kinda new about REST api (a php one), any references that could help? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you use PHP, and not a Java-based solution like Spring Boot. In any case, asking for references is off topic. In any case, you should [edit] your question to include the exception stacktrace.